# Move a .class to a desired position using jquery

Tags: jquery

one

```
<div id="2" class="h">two</div>
<div id="3" class="h">three</div>
<div id="4" class="h">4</div>
<div id="5" class="h">5</div>
```

When I click on 5 I want it to move to the position where id=3 is, using jQuery.

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, id's cannot start with a number, so I don't know how jQuery will react, but this should do it:

```
$('#5').click(function() {
    $('.h').eq(1).after($(this));
});
```

That would move #5 between #2 and #3 when clicked upon.

Comment: No such assumption was clear from your question. I've edited my answer.